# Proper name for bash $'...' strings?

Tags: bash, shell

What is the proper name for `$'...'` strings in Bash?

[Some sources](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) refer to this as "ANSI-C Quoting", but is there a nicer name for it (and is "ANSI-C Quoted String" the proper name for these strings)?

Comment: "abomination" :)

Comment: [The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) calls it that, pretty authoritative, I'd say – I'd have to check what it's called in ksh, where I believe it's from.

Comment: Ksh manual: "A single quoted string preceded by an unquoted $ is processed as an ANSI-C string"

Comment: Not sure why people are saying this is off topic.

Comment: I guess if there's no nicer name for these then "ANSI-C Quoted Strings" is the answer. I was hoping for something nicer like how people sometimes call `"..."` _interpolated strings_ and `'...'` _raw strings_ even though the "real" names are _double quoted strings_ and _single quoted strings_.